# interpreting this regular expression please var numbonly= /^[0-9]{3}\d+$/;

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var numbonly= /^[0-9]{3}\d+$/;
```

Please can you tell me what this regex means in JavaScript? I am very new to this thing and very stuck.

Comment: Odd. Why would someone use `[0-9]` and `\d` in the same regex?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @user2357112 I was about to point out the same

Comment: @user2357112 'The system shall allow any number of digits in field X; current limitation is 3' I'm guessing a requirement like this was given to someone didn't know regular expressions, and they cargo coded it from the first search result.

Comment: Can you explain why I cannot use [0-9] and \d in the same regex please

Comment: @user3295255—it's perfectly OK (though possibly redundant). In this case, it means match a string of at least 4 characters that is only digits.

Comment: first and foremost \d and [0-9] means the same thing i.e any digit between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 3):

`^` = String must start with

`[0-9]` = any digit 0-9

`{3}` = there must be 3 digits

`\d` = any digit (short for [0-9])

`+` = + is short for {1,}. Matches one or more times

`$` = end of string

So in English, there must be a digit [0-9], 3 times, then another digit [0-9] must be present 1 or more times.  So basically this means 4 or more digits.  So it could be written shorter, like this....

```
^\d{4,}$
```

Comment: @user3295255 I see you are new to stackoverflow.  If one of these answers successfully answered your question then click the checkmark next to it to accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
^     Matches the beginning of the String 
[0-9] Matches characters in the range 0-9 
{3}   Matches the previous token [0-9] exactly 3 times 
\d    Matches any digit character
+     Matches previous token \d one or more times 
$     Matches the end of the String
```